# How can I get gzip message ,extracted data, from rabbitmq in .NET (.NET Core)?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, gzip

How can I get **gzip** message from **rabbitmq** in .NET? (using some header)

Comment: By using `GZipStream`? It's hard to be more specific without seeing what code you're using to publish and retrieve messages. The basic RabbitMQ payload is just a bunch of bytes that you're free to interpret as you see fit.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for comment.

Comment: I'm only using gzip header (when publishing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AMQP protocol does not support compression. Any compression of message payloads would need to be done in your own code.  An example of such a method has been provided in another answer.

A better question would be "should I compress messages in RabbitMQ (or any other broker)?" and the answer to that would be "no."  If you're using messaging properly, the payloads are small - under 100kB, and the overhead of compression would yield a net negative performance penalty.  If you're finding a need to compress messages, you probably also need to choose another technology (i.e. a database).

Comment: I understand it. But I'm using C# and [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RabbitMQ.Client/5.1.2) package. So there have compression and  decompression implementation (for rabbitmq).

Comment: I added some detail and philosophy to my answer. Short answer is that you are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to decompress a gzip compressed queue message, you can use following:

```
  public static class Gzip {
    public static string Decompress(byte[] data) {
      using (var inStream = new MemoryStream(data))
      using (var outStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        using (var gzStream = new GZipStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
          gzStream.CopyTo(outStream);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outStream.ToArray());
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's good. Thanks. But I want use only RabbitMQ configuration (if it have).

Comment: I do not expect that RabbitMq is able to compress the messages.

Comment: RabbitMQ compressed use header. I just want decompress